# Creating a stack of strings in C

Tags: c, string, stack

I want to have a stack that takes strings.  I want to be able to push and pop strings off, as well as clear the whole stack.  I think C++ has some methods for this.  What about C?

Comment: Should your stack copy strings or use the pointers passed to them? It's much more easier with just saving the pointers, but almost useless, unless you know you're working with string literals and/or `char *` pointers whose strings are not going to change, and the pointers are not going to become invalid during their 'storage' on the stack.

Comment: The stack should copy strings, because the original strings might be overwritten.

Comment: Look up `strlen` + `malloc` + `strcpy`.  If you have `strdup`, you can use that (not ANSI C, but is POSIX.1), making things a bit easier for you.  Remember to `free` the strings when doing `pop` or `clear`.

Answer (score 11):

Quick-and-dirty untested example.  Uses a singly-linked list structure; elements are pushed onto and popped from the head of the list.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/**
 * Type for individual stack entry
 */
struct stack_entry {
  char *data;
  struct stack_entry *next;
}

/**
 * Type for stack instance
 */
struct stack_t
{
  struct stack_entry *head;
  size_t stackSize;  // not strictly necessary, but
                     // useful for logging
}

/**
 * Create a new stack instance
 */
struct stack_t *newStack(void)
{
  struct stack_t *stack = malloc(sizeof *stack);
  if (stack)
  {
    stack->head = NULL;
    stack->stackSize = 0;
  }
  return stack;
}

/**
 * Make a copy of the string to be stored (assumes  
 * strdup() or similar functionality is not
 * available
 */
char *copyString(char *str)
{
  char *tmp = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
  if (tmp)
    strcpy(tmp, str);
  return tmp;
}

/**
 * Push a value onto the stack
 */
void push(struct stack_t *theStack, char *value)
{
  struct stack_entry *entry = malloc(sizeof *entry); 
  if (entry)
  {
    entry->data = copyString(value);
    entry->next = theStack->head;
    theStack->head = entry;
    theStack->stackSize++;
  }
  else
  {
    // handle error here
  }
}

/**
 * Get the value at the top of the stack
 */
char *top(struct stack_t *theStack)
{
  if (theStack && theStack->head)
    return theStack->head->data;
  else
    return NULL;
}

/**
 * Pop the top element from the stack; this deletes both 
 * the stack entry and the string it points to
 */
void pop(struct stack_t *theStack)
{
  if (theStack->head != NULL)
  {
    struct stack_entry *tmp = theStack->head;
    theStack->head = theStack->head->next;
    free(tmp->data);
    free(tmp);
    theStack->stackSize--;
  }
}

/**
 * Clear all elements from the stack
 */
void clear (struct stack_t *theStack)
{
  while (theStack->head != NULL)
    pop(theStack);
}

/**
 * Destroy a stack instance
 */
void destroyStack(struct stack_t **theStack)
{
  clear(*theStack);
  free(*theStack);
  *theStack = NULL;
}
```

**Edit**

It would help to have an example of how to use it:

```
int main(void)
{
  struct stack_t *theStack = newStack();
  char *data;

  push(theStack, "foo");
  push(theStack, "bar");
  ...
  data = top(theStack);
  pop(theStack);
  ...
  clear(theStack);
  destroyStack(&theStack);
  ...
}
```

You can declare stacks as auto variables, rather than using newStack() and destroyStack(), you just need to make sure they're initialzed properly, as in

```
int main(void)
{
  struct stack_t myStack = {NULL, 0};
  push (&myStack, "this is a test");
  push (&myStack, "this is another test");
  ...
  clear(&myStack);
}
```

I'm just in the habit of creating pseudo constructors/destructors for everything.

Answer (score 3):

Try [GNU Obstacks](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libiberty/Obstacks.html).

From Wikipedia:

> In the C programming language, Obstack is a memory-management GNU extension to the C standard library. An "obstack" is a "stack" of "objects" (data items) which is dynamically managed.

Code example from Wikipedia:

```
char *x;
void *(*funcp)();

x = (char *) obstack_alloc(obptr, size); /* Use the macro. */
x = (char *) (obstack_alloc) (obptr, size); /* Call the function. */
funcp = obstack_alloc; /* Take the address of the function. */
```

**IMO what makes Obstacks special:** It does not need `malloc()` nor `free()`, but the memory still can be allocated «dynamically». It is like `alloca()` on steroids. It is also available on many platforms, since it is a part of the GNU C Library. Especially on embedded systems it might make more sense to use Obstacks instead of `malloc()`.

Answer (score 2):

See [Wikipedia's article about stacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(data_structure)#Implementation).